# Building ROS node with OpenCV2.2 includes

Tags: ros, vision-opencv, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unsure how to use cmake build system properly. I need to use OpenCV2.2 headers from my code but receive errors:

```
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/phippi.dir/src/crunch.o
In file included from /home/tonu/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi/src/crunch.c:9:
/home/tonu/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi/src/robot.h:44:31: error: imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
/home/tonu/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi/src/robot.h:45:31: error: highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory
```

CMakeLists.txt has needed entries I suppose

```
tonu@tonu-desktop:~/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi$ grep -i opencv CMakeLists.txt 
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(phippi ${OPENCV_INCLUDES})
tonu@tonu-desktop:~/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9682/building-ros-node-with-opencv2.2-includes/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2011-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of the opencv entries in CMakeLists.txt I have put the line

```
<depend package="opencv2"/>
```

in my manifest.xml. Then ros will generate the necessary inclusion and linkage flags for gcc automagically :-).

P.S: According to a comment in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/137/) thread, cturtle uses opencv 2.0, so you need to use diamondback for 2.2

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2